# RawContacts and Contacts

Tags: android, android-contacts

Add a type of contact (RawContact), sometimes they are combined with telephone contacts LOOKUP_KEY. It turns out that some contacts entries contain two RawContact'a one integrated phone, one of mine. The question is how to find out whether there is a Contacts RawContract my type? Or learn to RawContacts to which he refers Contacts?

Answer (score 1):

Match the "_id" of the contact to the "contact_id" of the raw contact.